# How to add column title to Excel while exporting result table from SQL query with Python

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have been trying to export a result table from a SQL query, but only the records inside the table is displayed in the Excel table. I am using MySQL and python(3.9.11) to run this code. Here is the code that I have been using to do so.

```py
import pymysql
dbconn = pymysql.connect(<db details>)
cus = dbconn.cursor()
cus.execute('sql query')
res = cus.fetchall()
data = []
for i in res:
    data += list(i)
var = open('main.csv','w')
for i in data:
    var.write(str(i))
var.close()
```

Also, the result table's all columns data is written in a single column.
I tried and adding a var.write('/n'), but it will convert the rows into columns.

Comment: Please use proper capitalization: the first word of a sentence, proper names and I (first person singular), all other words should be written lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pymysql
import csv
dbconn = pymysql.connect(DB Connection details)
cus = dbconn.cursor()
cus.execute("sql query here")
res = cus.fetchall()
column_names = [i[0] for i in cus.description]
fp = open('main.csv', 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator = '\n')
myFile.writerow(column_names)   
myFile.writerows(res)
```